# Unable to update tar.gzip despite using gunzip in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, tar

I am novice to Linux.
I am trying to update a `tar.gzip` located in `/path/to/dir` by another file located in `/path/to/new_dir/`. The file is the latest modified file in `path/to/new_dir/`. I am using the below commands but in a single line using `|`.

```
gunzip /path/to/dir/archive_raw_data.tar.gzip | find /path/to/new_dir/* -type f -name "*.txt" | 
sort -nr | head -n 1 | tar -rvf /path/to/raw_file_bkp/archive_raw_data.tar -T -| gzip 
/path/to/dir/archive_raw_data.tar
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
gzip: /path/to/dir/archive_raw_data.tar: No such file or directory
```

From the error it is clear that `gunzip` is not able to uncompress the `tar.gzip` file.

I am using centOS7.

What I am missing here?

Comment: By update do you mean add the file into the archive right? Note that the error message says that gzip cannot find the file `archive_raw_data.tar`. It is likely that you are missing the extension

Comment: Also note that you are working with a tar archive which is compressed with gzip. uncompressing it via gunzip leaves you with a tar archive. You might want to use `tar -xfz` instead. It would also help you troubleshooting if you would run one command after another instead of trying multiple pipes to get an idea where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: A pipeline runs all parts concurrently so you're trying to use the unzipped file before it exists. **You must _finish_ the gunzip before starting the `tar -rf file.tar`** and similarly wait for that to finish before doing the `gzip`. **And the suffix should be `.gz` not `.gzip`.** In short, `gunzip file.tar.gz ; ...choose filename(s)... | tar -rvf file.tar -T- ; gzip file.tar` (note semicolons) (or you can use `&&` instead, to abort if any part fails) (but NOT `&`)

Comment: piping a tar file into `find` isn't going to do anything useful.   `find` doesn't even read stdin (unless you use the non-standard GNU option `-files0-from -` to read the list of NUL-separated starting points), and certainly can't process a tar file.     What is it you're actually trying to do here?